# Change link text while div expands

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that expands once you click on a link; my issue, is I want to change the text while the div expands so that the link says "hide form". Can somebody please help me? I'm still new to jQuery..

The link to the page is here: http://biggz.co

Here's the jQuery I'm currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('a.contactForm').click(function() {

      jQuery('#contactForm').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('#contactForm').slideToggle('slow', function () {
    var txt = ($(this).css('display') == 'none') ? 'contact us directly':'Hide Form';
    $('.contactForm').text(txt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('a.contactForm').click(function() {

      jQuery('#contactForm').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Like

```
jQuery('a.contactForm').text('Hide Form');
```

So your code can be

```
jQuery('a.contactForm').click(function() {
  var text= $(this).text();
  if (text == 'Show Form')
    $(this).text('Hide From');
  else
    $(this).text('Show Form');
  jQuery('#contactForm').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: But when they click close, it doesn't change back, but thank you so much for trying!

Comment: Try the updated answer. It changes the text on both open and close